# How to list records that so many seen most in the day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list some records that were most seen on the day, so I have a table that keeps all records of the day (repeatedly).

I need to list it but I'm not having a logic to do this.

I tried do it:

```
<?php
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT token, data, category FROM news_system WHERE id=(SELECT new_id, SUM(clicks) FROM activity_system WHERE date='2017-11-22' GROUP by new_id)");
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();
    if($stmt1->num_rows >= 1) {
        $stmt1->bind_result($token, $data, $category);
        while($stmt1->fetch()) {
            echo "
                token is: {$token} <br />
                data is: {$data} <br />
                category: {$category} <br /> <br />
            ";       
        }
    }
?>
```

But it's not working, if you could help me i thank you.

Comment: there isn't enough code here, as in if you executed it, looped over it and echo'd something. You're going to have to define "not working".

Comment: *"But it's not working, if you could help me i thank you."* - Yeah, I tried and left. *"Soup's on."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- i edit the post, I do not know if you understood correctly, I need to list the records that were most viewed (CLICKS column) today (2017-11-22)

Comment: someone posted an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your activity_system has a column to link to news_system (in my query, I've guessed that it is named `news_token`), you can do a simple join to get the number of clicks per news item. Then just group it by the token, and order by the sum of the clicks, and you should be good to go.

```
select
    n.token, n.data, n.category, sum(a.clicks)
from
    news_system n
    join activity_system a
        on (n.token = a.news_token)
group by
    n.token, n.data, n.category
order by
    sum(a.clicks) desc
```